# Microsoft Power Automate no permite enviar imágenes con un tamaño mayor a 800kb

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, power-automate

Creé un flujo en Power Automate para enviar correos programados desde una lista de Sharepoint, la lista de Sharepoint contiene columnas como Asunto, Destinatario, Hipervínculo, Fecha y Hora de envío, y adicionalmente hago uso de la columna de archivos adjuntos para la imagen enviada.

Lo único que me interesa enviar en correos electrónicos programados es una imagen que estoy cargando y enviando desde la columna de archivos adjuntos.

Aquí el problema que se me presenta es que cuando la imagen supera los 800 kb no se envía en el cuerpo del correo, es decir que llega el correo sin la imagen solo con la información cargada en el asunto.

He construido el flujo de la siguiente manera:

- Cuando agregas un ítem o lo modificas posteriormente tendrás un retraso que es hasta la Fecha y Hora que se ha definido en la creación del nuevo Item de la lista de Sharepoint, luego obtendrás los cambios o propiedades para identificar si el correo ya se ha enviado y no se enviará cada vez que se cree el Item.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Luego obtengo los archivos adjuntos, que como mencioné es la imagen que se va a enviar en los correos programados y es con la que estoy teniendo problemas, después de obtener los archivos adjuntos inicializo una variable de tipo `String` que usaré más adelante.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aplico esto para cada uno, luego obtengo el contenido de los archivos adjuntos y los archivos adjuntos a la variable que previamente había inicializado el valor del hipervínculo y la imagen en el dataUri.

La expresión dataUri se define de la siguiente manera:

```
dataUri(outputs('Get_content_of_attachments')?['body'])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo valido la condición de que el correo no ha sido enviado y por ultimo preparo el contenido del correo enviando los parámetros que había ingresado previamente en la lista de Sharepoint, si están fijados en el cuerpo del correo hago uso la variable `str` que había inicializado previamente para él envió la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven este es el flujo que he construido para enviar imágenes en correos programados a través de una lista de Sharepoint, aquí el error que ya estoy presentando como comento es que cuando trato de enviar una imagen que supera los 800kb la imagen no se envía en el correo. ¿Hay alguna modificación que pueda cambiar en mi flujo? O otra forma de hacerlo pero que imágenes arriba de 800kb lleguen al correo.